# How to create column with other column's data?

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I want to create a column by using the other column's data. 
For example :

There are Modified Date , Modified By , Name  columns. I want to create a new column by using Modified Date. If Modified Date is TODAY , want to call it "NEW" or "EXPIRED" .

Is it possible with Sharepoint?
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Calculated` column type to achieve this. Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx)